# framing xpath expression with Dynamic Id clarification - webdriver with java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

below are the xpath the id parameter is dynamic

sampels:

```
//*[@id="00e46000000UZ8a_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page"]/div[1]/div"
//*[@id='00e6F000001ffnh_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page']/div[1]/div
```

so the begining 15 digits dynamically generated, so i try to find the element with below xpath

```
//[ends-with(@id,'_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page')]/div[1]/div
```

while executing i'm getting the below error

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[ends-with(@id,'_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page')]/div[1]/div because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//[ends-with(@id,'_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page')]/div[1]/div' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Selenium` doesn't support `ends-with()` syntax. You might need to use `contains()` instead

```
//*[contains(@id,'_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page')]/div[1]/div
```

or you also might use `substring()` to match value after 15 starting characters

```
//*[substring(@id, 16) = '_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page']/div[1]/div
```

Comment: Thanks, Contains not working but substring its working, can you please clarify why contains not working?

Comment: You mean element can't be find with `contains()` or you still get `invalid selector` exception?

Comment: Using //*[contains(@id,'_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page')]/div[1]/div getting same exception which is in my question

Comment: In `XPath` from your question and also in `XPath` suggested by @Guy there is no tag name neither wild-card (`*`) that matches any tag name. Make sure you use `//*[contains(@id, ... `, but not `//[contains(@id, ... `

Answer (score 1):

`ends-with` is [xpath 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_2.0#Function_library) function. Browsers support only [xpath 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Functions_and_operators). See [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(XML)#Query_technologies).

Use contains instead

```
//[contains(@id, '_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page')]/div[1]/div
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative way to deal with dynamic element you can use `CSSSelector` as well

For this :

```
//*[@id="00e46000000UZ8a_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page"]/div[1]/div
```

use `CSSselector` like this :

```
[id$='_RelatedCustomPermissionsSecurityList_page']>div>div
```

Also look into this :

```
css=a[id^='id_prefix_']

css=a[id$='_id_suffix']

css=a[id*='id_pattern']
```